# Flex mobile App, Adding a "status bar" to the bottom of a ViewNavigator

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile

I have my mobile flex application largely working and it is based on a ViewNavigatorApplication.

I would now like to add a kind of status bar at the bottom of the application that is visible across all views. This would be similar to the ActionBar at the top of the application. The status bar would just contain 2 pieces of text summarizing 2 pieces of general information about the application's state.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could go about this? Or any working examples?

thanks

Comment: Try editing the skin: https://github.com/apache/flex-sdk/blob/930b545e0cfad5c7ae8f08cd29e21a144d08227b/frameworks/projects/mobiletheme/src/spark/skins/mobile/ViewNavigatorSkin.as